# Interleaved VBO with coords,normals and color

Tags: c++, vbo, opengl-3

I have a question regarding interleaved vbo's. I have a structure that looks like this

```
struct VertexData{
    float x,y,z;   //vertex coordinates
    float normalx,normaly,normalz;  //vertex normal
    float cx,cy,cz;  //vertex color
};
```

And this is how i create my VBO,VAO,IBO:

```
    //creat OpenGL objects to use in drawing
    unsigned int gl_vertex_array_object, gl_vertex_buffer_object, gl_index_buffer_object;

    //vertex array object 
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &gl_vertex_array_object);
    glBindVertexArray(gl_vertex_array_object);

    //vertex buffer object -> we hold the vertices 
    glGenBuffers(1,&gl_vertex_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_vertex_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(VertexData), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    //index buffer object -> we hold the index of vertex
    glGenBuffers(1,&gl_index_buffer_object);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl_index_buffer_object);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size()*sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //the connection between attributes, interleaved data
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)0);                       //send positions on pipe 0
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(sizeof(float)*3));       //send normals on pipe 1
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(3*sizeof(float)*3));     //send colors on pipe 2

    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(sizeof(float)*3));   
    glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(3*sizeof(float)*3));

    vao = gl_vertex_array_object;
    vbo = gl_vertex_buffer_object;
    ibo = gl_index_buffer_object;
    num_indices = indices.size();
```

If my VBO is a vector of VertexData , does it mean it is interleaved ? And did i send the data correct above ? with stride and offset ?
All this is in another class. Here is how i load the mesh and draw it in the main class

```
    //load
 teren::loadTerrain("resurse\\heightmap.bmp","resurse\\heightmap_color.bmp",mesh_vao_ground, mesh_vbo_ground, mesh_ibo_ground, mesh_num_indices_ground,20);
    //draw
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader_curent, "model_matrix"),1,false,glm::value_ptr(matrice_translatie));
    glBindVertexArray(mesh_vao_ground);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh_num_indices_ground, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

My terrain is drawn but it has a weird colouring. It has pink and blue and whatnot, doesn't look anything like the color image from which i get my vertex colors. Here is my gourard vertex shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;       
layout(location = 1) in vec3 in_normal; 
layout(location = 2) in vec3 in_color;  

uniform mat4 model_matrix, view_matrix, projection_matrix;
uniform vec3 light_position;
uniform vec3 eye_position;
uniform int material_shininess;
uniform float material_kd;
uniform float material_ks;

out vec3 light;
void main(){


gl_Position = projection_matrix*view_matrix*model_matrix*vec4(in_position,1.0); 
float fDiffuseIntensity = material_kd * max(0.0, dot(normalize(in_normal), normalize(light_position)));
light = material_ks * in_color * fDiffuseIntensity;
}
```

And my gourard fragment shader:

```
in vec3 light;
out vec4 out_color;

void main()
{
    out_color = vec4(light,1.0);
}
```

I am really stuck right now. Is it a problem with my shaders or my vbo/attributes,etc or maybe even both. I would really appreciate some help.(PS:If in the vertex shader i change to light=in_color , everything is white).I also have a light rotating above the terrain. Here is a photo of what is happening:
http://i44.tinypic.com/69j0cg.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(3*sizeof(float)*3));
```

Should be:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(sizeof(float)*6));
```

Also you don't need these stuffs:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(sizeof(float)*3));   
glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(VertexData),(void*)(3*sizeof(float)*3));
```

All the rest is correct.

---

> does it mean it is interleaved?

Yes.

---

Language lawyers will probably tell you that since the compiler is allowed to add padding anywhere inside the `VertexData` struct, the correct approach to pass these data to GL would be to manually convert your vector of `VertexData` to a buffer of floats. Practically speaking, no compiler pads floats inside a struct like that.

Comment: Yes i was considering converting the vertex buffer to a float buffer and if it's better off doing so no problem for me.I changed that line and now it seems to render better (also when i saved the colors i forgot to divide by 255 , my bad) but i still have a incorrect result.My colored heightmap has mostly a brown color but the rendered mesh is green , so thats odd.Wonder if the lighting is the problem, or my normal calculation.Gotta figure this out.

Comment: Tried with a different set of images.Still weird results.Here is the rendered terrain http://i41.tinypic.com/16kzvyb.jpg. Some of the colors look right but the rest is gibberish . Here is the image used to extract the colors: http://read.pudn.com/downloads186/sourcecode/windows/opengl/871583/res/earth__.jpg

Comment: Problem solved,I accepted your answer sbabbi, thank you. In case some1 is interested I was saving r,g,b values as floats whereas the pixels were a 1D array of char so i changed to unsigned char then divided by 255.0f to convert to float.